# Log To AWS CloudTrail Lambda Function Execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudtrail

New to AWS here, so please bare that in mind.

But I can't seem to figure out how to achieve my goal.

My goal is to log into AWS cloud trail all function executions of my lambda functions.
I want to see when they are executed.

What I did so far.

**1. Created Trail**

Created a trail (data event) that will log the events of the specified lambda functions into S3.

**2. Created Event Data Store**

Created event data store that will let me view the trail logs? I am actually blurry on this part.

**3. Copied trail events into the created event data store above**

I did this because having just step 2 above does not show the events on clouldtrail.

So on step 1, it seemed to work. I test run the lambda function and after a couple of minutes (not instant), the s3 resource associated to the trail did indeed created a log. It is gzipped (*.json.gz)

So at least I think that part is working as expected?

Obviously I want to display this information in a visually pleasing manner rather than viewing the log directly manually hince I did steps 2 and 3, but, it does not seem to show the event data into the lake dashboard.

When I click run queries, on specified correct dates, it just say no data available.

I even did step 3 again to make sure the s3 contains logs before doing step 3 but still no good.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: To be sure, you mean Cloudtrail and not Cloudwatch? https://blog.awsfundamentals.com/cloudwatch-vs-cloudtrail-understanding-the-differences

Comment: Yes cloudtrail not cloudwatch. I have setup my lambda function though to log console.logs into cloudwatch and technically I can use these logs in cloud watch to view the invocations of these lambda functions. I am basically wanting a better way of viewing the invocation because I found out that close proximity invocations of the same lambda function logs on the same log stream. I want something to display a record per invocations. Again new to AWS. Not even sure if what I am doing is the best way to do what I want to do.